# LLVM Pass that renames all functions

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm

Below is an LLVM pass that I've written to rename all functions in an LLVM bitcode file. I would appreciate tips on what is well done and what is poorly done in the code below. In particular, is there a better way to go about writing LLVM passes. Bear in mind that I'm a novice at programming and so would also appreciate it if you could direct me to any resources that would be useful in improving my C++ code.

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SmallString.h"
#include "llvm/Analysis/TargetLibraryInfo.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/TypeFinder.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {

  struct FunctionRenamer : public ModulePass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification
    FunctionRenamer() : ModulePass(ID) {
      initializeFunctionRenamerPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
    }

    void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
      AU.addRequired<TargetLibraryInfoWrapperPass>();
      AU.setPreservesAll();
    }

    bool runOnModule(Module &M) override {
      // Rename all functions
      const TargetLibraryInfo &TLI =
        getAnalysis<TargetLibraryInforWrapperPass>().getTLI();
      for (auto &F : M) {
        StringRef Name = F.getName();
        LibFunc Tmp;
        // Leave library functions alone because their presence or absence
        // could affect the behaviour of other passes.
        if (Name.startswith("llvm.") || (!Name.empty() && Name[0] == 1) ||
            TLI.getLibFunc(F, Tmp))
          continue;

        F.setName(Name + "_2");
      }
      return true;
    }
  };
}

char FunctionRenamer::ID = 0;
INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(FunctionRenamer, "functionrenamer",
                      "Rename all functions", false, false);
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(TargetLibraryInfoWrapperPass);
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(FunctionRenamer, "functionrenamer",
                    "Rename all functions", false, false);
// ===-------------------------------------------------------==//
//
// Function Renamer - Renames all functions
//
ModulePass *llvm::createFunctionRenamerPass() {
  return new FunctionRenamer();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `TargetLibraryInforWrapperPass` seems to have one `r` too many.
2. Try using `auto` a bit more extensively. [Almost always `auto`](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)
3. Did you really mean `'\1'` or should that be `'1'` in the following line? Either way, use a character-literal to make it obvious it's not an error.

   ```
   if (Name.startswith("llvm.") || (!Name.empty() && Name[0] == 1) ||
                                                                ^
   ```
4. The same applies to `using namespace llvm;` as to `using namespace std;`:
   Don't do it. Read "[Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)" for why.